# What is the ungrammatical sentence among those?

Tags: grammar

This is my grammar quiz of finding out the ungrammatical.

> [image]
>
> Elephants are large land-dwelling mammals characterized by their long snouts and ivory tusks. Only three of the hundreds of elephant species that once existed remain at this time, namely, savanna, forest, and Asian elephants. The only two continents which these surviving species can be found are Africa and Asia. Climate change, habitat loss, and human intrusion have contributed to the elephant's status as an endangered animal.

My non-native teacher said the answer should be (C) for not placing 'In' before 'Which'. Is she correct? And the free grammar checker in the web also pointed out (C) but for different reason. It suggested to switch 'Can be found' to some other verb in active voice, which I don't get it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence (C) is ungrammatical as it is.

Your teacher's suggestion would make it grammatical:

> The only two continents **in** which these surviving species can be found are Africa and Asia.

But so would replacing "can be found" with "some other verb in active voice":

> The only two continents which these surviving species **inhabit** are Africa and Asia.

---

If you use an appropriate active verb here, you don't need to use a preposition.